# What is our stance on questions "is it safe to do X with medical condition Y"?

Tags: discussion, scope

What is our stance on questions "is it safe to do X with medical condition Y"? Are they on-topic or off-topic?

[Example](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/9630/43):

> Title: Is it safe to drive with a torn acl?
>
> Last week, I tore my ACL (complete tear). Since then I've progressed
>   from being immobilised / limited to crunches to being able to walk
>   around with the support of a knee brace.
>
> I do not have the full range of motion - my leg only bends a bit more
>   than 90 degrees - and there is some instability, i.e. walking up and
>   down stairs is uncomfortable.
>
> I'm wondering if it is safe to drive.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, it depends on the actual question, but I think that in most cases it constitutes personal medical advice - since many conditions can be presented in various forms and/or various degrees of severity, so a physician would need to assess all the factors and decide what is safe and what isn't for each individual patient.